# Find specific word in column and copy the adjacent value to different column

Tags: excel, vba

I need a help in excel VBA

[image]

I would need to find a text (header - e.g. Account) The cell with word "Account" will be always in the column C
and copy value from adjacent column C and paste them on same sheet to Column A
till the value present in column C (like - 09:00-09:30 till it end )

Column 
A   B   C

```
    Account Test1
    Group   XXX
    Date    Mon24 Jun, 2019

    09:00-09:30 
    09:30-10:00 
    10:00-10:30 
    10:30-11:00 
    11:00-11:30 
    11:30-12:00 
    12:00-12:30 
    12:30-13:00 
    13:00-13:30 
    17:30-18:00 


    Account Test2
    Group   YYY
    Date    Mon24 Jun, 2019

    09:00-09:30 
    09:30-10:00 
    10:00-10:30 
    10:30-11:00 
    11:00-11:30 
    11:30-12:00 
    12:00-12:30 
    12:30-13:00 
    13:00-13:30 
    17:30-18:00
```

Comment: Sounds doable through formula tbh

Comment: Please provide with solution @JvdV , actually there is lot more test in between 2 accounts & further i have to copy paste all combined data to another new sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
Sub ApplyHeader()
    Dim c As Range, Acc$, Grp$

    'Loops through first to last used i column C
    For Each c In Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))

        'Stores value from adjacent cell if it says "Account".
        If c.Value = "Account" Then Acc = c.Offset(, 1).Value

        'Stores value from adjacent cell if it says "Group".
        If c.Value = "Group" Then Grp = c.Offset(, 1).Value

        'Applies stored values in columns to the left if first character is numerical.
        If IsNumeric(Left(c.Value, 1)) Then
            c.Offset(, -2).Value = Acc
            c.Offset(, -1).Value = Grp
        End If
    Next c

    'Removes stored values from "memory".
    Acc = "": Grp = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried but not working can you please elaborate, how exactly it work

Comment: Awesome Man @Asusual thnxsssssss a Lot

Comment: i have found d way of completing d task  @AsUsual  but ur 1st piece of code is awesome

Comment: @Nitin I was probably an idiot for helping you with this, as in "setting a bad example", but I'm no expert either. You should not post another question as an answer to your question, this should be a new question, tags doesn't work in the description text and you should really read this [ask] if you expect an answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

@AsUsual

I have found d way -->

```
Sub Copy()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet


Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

j = 1
For Each c In Source.Range("C1:C4000")
    If IsNumeric(Left(c.Value, 1)) Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
```

End Sub